# wordpress changing the admin message on error

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to create a function on function.php for editing error message of excerpt field text on editing post and create post if the length of text is longer to 50 character the author will git error message maximum character allowed is 50 max.
i did try this code :

```
function general_admin_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    echo '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
             <p>maximum character allowed is 50 max</p>
         </div>';
}


function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr) {

    if (strlen($data["post_excerpt"]) > 50){
        
        return add_action('admin_notices', 'general_admin_notice');
    }
    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );
```

Not working I always getting :
Updating failed. Could not update post in the database.

I tried this code :

```
function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr) {

    if (strlen($data["post_excerpt"]) > 50){
        
        return '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
        <p>maximum character allowed is 50 max</p>
    </div>';
    }
    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );
```

nothing work

Comment: Your approach is totally wrong, you can't validate post data like this in the backend, you'll have to use JS/jQuery for validation and error message printing. If  you need server-side validation then you'll have to send an AJAX request, until your JS validation is not true then you need to prevent form submit using JS/jQuery

Comment: can you explain more because I searched everywhere to mdify the messages but I didn't find any place where to do it